# Pass List with custom object to another activity android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `List<News> new ArrayList<News>();`  I need to pass this list to another activity and retrieve object from it to assign it to String values.

News.java

```
 public class News 
{


    String title;
    String description;
    String thumbnail;
    String newsUrl;
    String body;
    String newsBigImage ;
    String newsComments ;
    String newsViews;
    String publishedDate;
    String articleGuid;
    String newsSourceId;
    String newsId ;
    String publisherName;
    String newsSourceTitle;
    String color;

    News(String title, String description, String thumbnail, String newsUrl, String body, String newsBigImage,  String newsComments,  String newsViews,
    String publishedDate,
    String articleGuid,
    String newsSourceId,
    String newsId ,
    String publisherName,
    String newsSourceTitle )
    {

        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.articleGuid =articleGuid;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.newsUrl = newsUrl;
        this.body = body;
        this.newsBigImage = newsBigImage;
        this.newsComments = newsComments;
        this.newsViews = newsViews;
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
        this.newsId = newsId;
        this.newsSourceId = newsSourceId;
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
        //this.color = color;
        this.newsSourceTitle  =newsSourceTitle;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getNewsUrl() {
        return newsUrl;
    }

    public void setNewsUrl(String newsUrl) {
        this.newsUrl = newsUrl;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getNewsBigImage() {
        return newsBigImage;
    }

    public void setNewsBigImage(String newsBigImage) {
        this.newsBigImage = newsBigImage;
    }

    public String getNewsComments() {
        return newsComments;
    }

    public void setNewsComments(String newsComments) {
        this.newsComments = newsComments;
    }

    public String getNewsViews() {
        return newsViews;
    }

    public void setNewsViews(String newsViews) {
        this.newsViews = newsViews;
    }

    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }

    public String getArticleGuid() {
        return articleGuid;
    }

    public void setArticleGuid(String articleGuid) {
        this.articleGuid = articleGuid;
    }

    public String getNewsSourceId() {
        return newsSourceId;
    }

    public void setNewsSourceId(String newsSourceId) {
        this.newsSourceId = newsSourceId;
    }

    public String getNewsId() {
        return newsId;
    }

    public void setNewsId(String newsId) {
        this.newsId = newsId;
    }

    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    public String getNewsSourceTitle() {
        return newsSourceTitle;
    }

    public void setNewsSourceTitle(String newsSourceTitle) {
        this.newsSourceTitle = newsSourceTitle;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }


}
```

I pass values like:-

```
myNewsList.add(new News(title, description, thumbnail, newsUrl, body, newsBigImage, newsComments, newsViews, publishedDate, articleGuid, newsSourceId, newsId, publisherName, newsSourceTitle));
```

Then I pass this list to an ListAdapter to show it in a ListView.

```
 itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(myContext, myNewsList);

        newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Now, When the user clicks a listview item, I want to pass the `myNewsList` to the new activity and retrieve items from it and assign it to another Strings in that class.

```
ewsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myDialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext).show(getActivity(), "Fetching news..", "Just a moment");



                    //News myMap = myNewsList.get(position);
                    Intent newsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),NewsDetails.class);

                    startActivity(newsIntent);
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 4):

implements a parcelable interface so your class will look like

```
public class News implements Parcelable {


String title;
String description;
String thumbnail;
String newsUrl;
String body;
String newsBigImage ;
String newsComments ;
String newsViews;
String publishedDate;
String articleGuid;
String newsSourceId;
String newsId ;
String publisherName;
String newsSourceTitle;
String color;


protected News(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
    thumbnail = in.readString();
    newsUrl = in.readString();
    body = in.readString();
    newsBigImage = in.readString();
    newsComments = in.readString();
    newsViews = in.readString();
    publishedDate = in.readString();
    articleGuid = in.readString();
    newsSourceId = in.readString();
    newsId = in.readString();
    publisherName = in.readString();
    newsSourceTitle = in.readString();
    color = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(thumbnail);
    dest.writeString(newsUrl);
    dest.writeString(body);
    dest.writeString(newsBigImage);
    dest.writeString(newsComments);
    dest.writeString(newsViews);
    dest.writeString(publishedDate);
    dest.writeString(articleGuid);
    dest.writeString(newsSourceId);
    dest.writeString(newsId);
    dest.writeString(publisherName);
    dest.writeString(newsSourceTitle);
    dest.writeString(color);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<News> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<News>() {
    @Override
    public News createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new News(in);
    }

    @Override
    public News[] newArray(int size) {
        return new News[size];
    }
};
```

}

and you can pass now this in intent extra like

```
intent.putExtra("newsObject", obj);
```

and for passing arraylist do `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("newsList", arr);`

and in next activity get like

```
News news = (News)intent.getParcelableExtra("newsObject");
```

and for getting arraylist do

```
ArrayList<News> news = (ArrayList<News>)intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("newsList");
```

Comment: I somehow get a null for values in my other Activity when I retrieve them.

Comment: Cant I pass the list directly?

Comment: did you get the intent by calling . getIntent()

Comment: ya I did do it. How can I pass the list directly?

Comment: you will pass the list as object but when getting it, call getParcelableArrayListExtra. (it will sound like this. see in the intellisence)

Comment: Can you please explain by updating your answer?

Comment: I get an error `The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<News>)`

Comment: How do I get the values from the list in the next activity then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Seriazable` or `Parceable` interface implementation for this.

Comment: I will talk you later if you think this should be comment

Answer (score 0):

In NewsDetails class just you want to show the description so call getters method of model class and show there,  or else follow above solution

Comment: what "above solution"?

Comment: still you are stuck there...i mean follow what @Mick has posted here

Answer (score 0):

first, create a getter method to retreive your object in adapter.. returning your List then you call your getter in your activity, then you create your intent.